# React Native equivalent to limitTo and orderBy

Tags: react-native

I'm new to `React Native` so excuse my ignorance but after reading the documentation, I can't seem to find anything to order or limit the array in the `ListView` like `Angular` its `limitTo` and `orderBy`.

For example I want to limit my ListView to 10 items order by date.

`pageSize={10}` doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You want to display only 10 items in listview irrespective of list size?

Comment: I have an array of 100+ items but would love to limit to 10 so I can order it by top 10 most viewed

Comment: ok. You will have to apply the logic on array itself, then pass the filtered array to listView. Mostly there is no property you can directly set to ListView which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageSize` prop is actually used to determine the number of rows to be rendered per event-loop, rather than allowing for pagination. If you want to limit the `<ListView />` you'll need to operate on the data-source itself:

```
// Load the data to be used
let myData = fetchData()

let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})

this.setState({
  rows: dataSource.cloneWithRows(myData.slice(0, 10))
})
```